# Nginx not redirect to https docker ports

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, parse-server

Im using Docker compose with mongoDB,Parse server and Parse Dashboard, with different ports.
My Nginx its working good except when I enter the server ip with the ports of the docker images.

```
 - www.mydomain.com -> https
 - 1.21.221.21 (my ip) -> https
 - 1.21.221.21:4040 -> http
```

Here is my nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Any idea? Im getting crazy on sunday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you request `1.21.221.21:80` you have access to nginx, and it redirect you to https.

But when you have request `1.21.221.21:4040` (app port) your request goes directly to app. Nginx does`t handle this request.

Comment: So, its possible to block this port with nginx?

Comment: with nginx no. you need remove `4040` port exposing in docker-compose file. Or block this port by firewall of your server.

Comment: Ok I think the right question is.. Its possible to redirect this port with nginx?
If I remove the exposing docker port I cant access to my parse server, the same with the firewall, I need this port opened but redirecting the traffic to https

Answer (score 0):

Try to proxy pass to the correct ports

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
}
```

note that the above port is set to 3001, you will have to change it to :4040

Comment: Of course I have this config, but the problem is enter by ip or domain